# Laravel Models - Grabbing Object's ID

Tags: php, laravel, model

I know that one can create an object from a model that represents a particular entry in the DB by using `ModelName::find($model_id)`.  What I'm curious about is how one goes about grabbing the current ID within the model on a function - so say that I wanted to expand the User model so that it will return all of the songs uploaded by said user.

I want to just be able to call `$user = User::find($user_id)` to grab the relevant user, and then call the function from within the model like so: `$user->list_songs()`;.  How do I, within this function in the model (public function list_songs()), check to see what the current id is?  I'm currently passing it as a variable, and this seems counter-intuitive to the idea of a model.

Comment: I think within the model, you can use `$this->attributeName` so you should be able to get the current user object's id by `$this->id` Plus, why not use relations to get user uploaded songs ?

Comment: It was a poor example, I just didn't wish to post the actual one.  Thanks!

Comment: So, `$this->id` is working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Within the model you can simply use `$this->id` so long as the model has been saved to the database.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I'll add you can use `$this->getKey()` in the case of the table's primary key being defined as something besides `id`.